# Split MYSQL results to contain n sizes per slice

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This question is basically similar to SoulieBaby's question here:[Split MYSQL results into 4 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237011/split-mysql-results-into-4-arrays), except that I wanted to split the result to contain a specific length.

Say, I wanted the result of an array which has a length of 9 to be splitted and have the splitted array to contain 5 lengths. So first array will have 5 and second will have 4.

Is this possible?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk). `array_chunk( $result, ceil(count($result)/5));` like in the second answer.

Comment: @air4x, quick answer! I am currently reading the link you've given and I think you showed me the right solution. Maybe you can post your question so I can select it as the answer? Thanks again!

Comment: If you are not going to use all of the data, for instance if you are doing pagination, one option is to limit your query to the database. Much faster, especially if the dataset is large.

Comment: Using `array_chunk($array, 5)` would split the whole set into chunks of size 5 (the last chunk might contain less), which is what you're after I think.

Comment: @Nils, unfortunately I need to get all the data and display it in a carousel effect. Btw, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I can't figure out a way to chunk the data to fit to a certain number of grid. Too bad they don't have an option to just set a number of item to  display for Bootstrap's Carousel component. Anyway, thanks for your answer, that's what I first planned too by using limits but found it harder.

Comment: @Jack, yes, that's what I wanted. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced question wanted to always have 4 chunks, therefore the solution was to create chunks of size `ceil(count($array) / 5)`.

This case is easier, the (maximum) size is constant but the number of chunks vary.

Therefore the answer is simply:

```
array_chunk($array, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE split (in data varchar(500),in cad char(1))
BEGIN
    declare pos int default 0;
    declare numero int default 0;
    declare van int default 0;
    declare a varchar(500) default '';
    drop TEMPORARY table IF EXISTS tmp_split;
    create TEMPORARY table tmp_split(dato varchar(500)) ENGINE=MEMORY; 

    set pos=LOCATE(cad,data);
    while pos<>0 do
        set numero=numero+1;
        set pos=LOCATE(cad,data,pos+1);
    end while;
    set a=SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,cad,1);
    while numero>van do        
        set data=SUBSTRING(data,LENGTH(a)+2);
        insert into tmp_split values (a);
        set a=SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,cad,1);
        set van=van+1;
    end while;
    insert into tmp_split values (a);
    select * from tmp_split;
END
```

---

`call split('1,2,5,52,64,365,9714,253,6697,8,9,2,62',',');`